# Mass matrix for inverse seesaw mechanism

Tags: mass, standard-model, neutrinos, eigenvalue, beyond-the-standard-model

I am having trouble in diagonalizing analytically the mass matrix associated to the inverse seesaw mechanism with lagrangian:
$L= -y_1\bar{L}\tilde{H}N_{R_1} - -y_2\bar{L}\tilde{H}N_{R_2} + N_{R_1}^TM_{R_1}C^\dagger N_{R_1} + N_{R_2}^TM_{R_2}C^\dagger N_{R_2} +\Lambda \bar{N_{R_1}}N_{R_2}^C + h.c. $

Where the mass matrix is given by:

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & y_1 v_H/ \sqrt{2} & y_2 v_H/ \sqrt{2}\\
y_1v_H/\sqrt{2} & M_{R_1} & \Lambda \\
y_2v_H/\sqrt{2} & \Lambda & M_{R_2}
\end{pmatrix}

If we take a U(1) where L has charge 1, $N_{R_1}$ has charge 1 and $N_{R_1}$ has charge -1, we will obtain that $y_2v_H/\sqrt{2}, M_{R_1}$ and $M_{R_2}$ have to be small.
The resulting eigenvalue for the neutrino mass should be:

$m_{\nu} = \frac{v_H^2}{2(\Lambda^2 - \mu \mu')}[\mu y_1^2 + y_2^2 \mu' -2\Lambda y_2y_1] $
where $\mu$ and $\mu'$ have been used insted of $M_{R_1}$ and $M_{R_2}$ respectively.

I have tried to obtain this result but I can't, even by using approximation for the small values I don't recover the denominator in any way. Can someone tell me what could I be doing wrong in the procedure and if there's some way to get this result?

Comment: You have cloyed your expression with too many superfluous parameters, and omitted crucial information on their relative sizes, providing irrelevant information instead. You are asking about the smallest eigenvalue of a 3x3 matrix after all.  Introduce the μs and parameters *a,b* for the effective Yukawa couplings, and describe what your difficulty is. Large and small components of your matrix should jump at you and the reader.

Comment: I don't have a reference, these are just notes taken in class. It should have been just an introduction on the topic so no computations were required and therefore it wasn't treated in detail, but I have to do this diagonalization for other reasons

Comment: Mathematica should provide the eigenvalues... As a warmup,  try $y_2=0$. give your variables simple names.

Comment: Yes, but I have to do both the analytic and numerical computation and then compare the two for an assignment

Comment: Mathematica would provide the analytic one, and confirm it.

Comment: Define $y_1v/\sqrt 2= a$,  $y_2=0$, $M_{R1}=M_{R2}\equiv b$ small, ignore $O(b^2)$ terms. The eigenvalues are now transparent, so you may see your target mass is wrong: it does *not* reduce to the smallest eigenvalue!